# What does '101' reputation (on many sites) means in profiles of some high rep users?

Tags: discussion

Let me explain a bit what I am trying to ask. So I am giving links of profiles of two high rep users. For example, two of our mods.

[schroeder's profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1058123/schroeder?tab=accounts)

He is member of 22 sites but as you can see, on some sites he has '101' reputation but have no questions and answers at all!

Here is our other mod:

[Jeff Ferland](https://stackexchange.com/users/32523/jeff-ferland?tab=accounts)

Same is true for him also.

So how it is possible to have some reputation on a site having no questions and answers at all? And what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get +100 if you are trusted<sup>*</sup> on at least one site. It is done so that someone who has gained reputation on one site will automatically be able to post to protected questions on another site (an action that requires rep), for example. In other words, once you are trusted on one site, you get a minimum amount of trust on all other sites on the network. This is called the [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/). This is given whenever you join a new site and have 200 reputation or more on an existing site.

<sub>* Being trusted enough to gain the association bonus on other sites does not imply that you are a [Trusted User](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), which is a specific privilege milestone for an individual site that comes at a much higher rep threshold: 20,000.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

https://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation :

> You gain reputation when:
>   …
>
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

More details [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/).

Comment: But *when* +100 is awarded? when you join another site?

Comment: @daya yes. The bonus will be given when joining (read: creating a new account on) that site.

Comment: @AndrewT. *did you mean* creating a separate account on each SE awards +100 *automatically*. As you can see schroeder have 10 sites with '101' rep so that means he has *separate accounts on that SE* ?

Comment: @daya You have one parent account (with one password, etc), and every site you join provides you with a new account with its own rep and, optionally, its own displayed username (e.g. another moderator we have is called [Rory Alsop](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/485/rory-alsop) on [security.se], but [Doktor Mayhem](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/104/doktor-mayhem) on [music.se]). Some, like me, have the same username, but a different profile image on some sites.

Comment: @forest I totally understands your comment but the *question* was *how* this +100 comes instead of just '1' rep(which is by default when you join a new SE). I have total of 8 sites in my profiles but the sites in which I have no questions and answers have just '1' rep.Did you get the point?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You only get +100 if you are trusted on at least one site. It is done so that someone who has gained reputation on one site will automatically be able to post to protected questions on another site. In other words, once you are trusted on one site, you get a minimum amount of trust on all other sites on the network.

Comment: @forest Yeah! Please add this as an answer and also add on *which* milestone you considered as "trusted" user

Comment: @daya I don't actually remember which milestone triggers the "trusted" status.

Comment: @forest No problem!, apart from that milestone, add your comment as answer for future readers as well because imo the existing answer didn't *really* answer the question

Comment: @daya Done. I've also found out what the threshold is (at least 200 rep on any site). To be fair, AviD's answer _does_ link to the same page which I got my information from!

Comment: Indeed! My bad I didn't read that blog. Sorry @AviD